# Android app launcher which allows creating groups of apps in the app drawer like Windows 10 menu (not folders)

Tags: android, launcher

Is there any Android app launcher which can create collapsible groups of apps using lines (dividers) or something in the app drawer? I am aware we can use folders or tabs but I would like to be able to have multiple groups open at once. I have tried Nova, Apex, Poco, Microsoft launcher and others but they don't have this functionality. Some launchers sort apps smartly but again they show up as different groups on different tabs. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: A possible pointer can probably be provided by my app listings, like the one for [app organizers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize). I've not tried them, so I cannot tell you which would match – but while waiting for recommendations, you might wish to check. If you find a good candidate, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)